# Java Security : Keytool

Tags: security

I am using java's KeyTool to generate a self-signed certificate. Just wanted to know if there is a way to create a self signed certificate with a Private Key that has no password.

I know OpenSsl does allow you to do that.

Comment: Hmm, on the one hand this is about a command line tool, on the other hand that CLI tool is only part of an SDK. I guess it is allowed :)

Comment: Any idea how can we do that ? What options should be specified so that password will not be prompted and certificate will be created with no password ?  
C:\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned2 -keystore keystore1.jks  
-dname "CN=`localhost`, OU=Example Department, O=Example Company,L=Birmingham, ST=West Midlands, C=GB" -storepass password1 -validity 360  
-keysize 2048 -noprompt  
Enter key password for <selfsigned2>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, Oracle's Java team has already identified that the PKCS#12 support should be upgraded in the next version of Java.